# Responsive Facebook Comments

Tags: facebook, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make "Facebook Comments", or any other Facebook out of the box plugin responsive to a grid rather than using fixed widths?

I'm currently using Bootstrap 3 grid for my site, my problem is that Facebook Comments use fixed width & height, this makes it look bad when the width of the container changes.

While the Twitters Timeline feed is responsive and look awesome, I still need both to be responsive on my webpage.

The design of "Facebook comments" could be improved, as it looks really bad on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is a facebook comments that has responsive design.

Instead of facebook comments you can use **3rd Party Commenting System** [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) with responsive design including facebook, twitter, google and many more comment systems.

You worth have a look in there. I tested Disqus with their responsive design it worked fine.